# How can I only show 100 characters of a post?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I am currently creating a blog site and on home page, I only want 100 character of the paragraph to show.After that I want only ...(3 dots) to shown How can I do that using javascript or css?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqgvJ.jpg)

I want it to look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9btf.jpg)

Comment: you mean text-overflow ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Only Html & Css, you can use something like this:

```
p {
     width: 250px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here are some examples of that:  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Using Javascript, you could use something like this:

```
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector),
        truncated = element.innerText;

    if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
        truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
    }
    return truncated;
}
//You can then call the function with this
document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 107);
```

Here's an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/sgjGe/1/

Answer (score 4):

Use the javascript [Substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

```
  <p> <%= post.body.substring(1, 100) + "..." %> </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p> <%= post.content.substring(0, 100) + "..."  %> </p>
```

This would return 100 characters exactly, since the '100' indicates the number in the series to be excluded. The string displayed would be from 1st element (at index 0) to the 100th element (at index 99).

I'm also doing Angela's challenge. Lol!

Answer (score 0):

`<p> <%= post.postText.substring(1, 100) + "..." %> </p>`

here, `post.postText` returns the paragraph String.

If you are doing Angela's Challenge this would help.

Comment: the substring is actually (0, 100) and not (1, 100).

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><%= post.content.substring(1, 100) + "..." %></p>
```

As this code helps me a lot I think it should help you also.
keep going I'm also doing angela's challenge right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following methods (assuming we are working with ejs):

1. We can use the `substring()` method: The `substring(a, b)` method extracts characters, between two indices (positions a and b respectively), from a string, and returns the substring.

   Example:

   ```js
   let text = "I love javascript";
   <%= text.substring(0, 6)+"..." %>
   ```

   This will display the first 5 characters between 0 and 6 of the text followed by the 3 dots: `I love...`
2. We can also use the `slice()` method:
   Example:

   ```js
   <%= text.split(" ").slice(0, 2).join(" ") %>
   ```

   This will limit the string of text to 2 words separated by a space: `I love`.

NB: The second method is more suitable when working on elements in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript Substring inbuilt function.

Comment: This is useful, but If you show an example could be more productive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As this code helps me a lot I think it should help you also. keep going I'm also doing angela's challenge right now.

```
<p><%= post.content.substring(1, 100) + "..." %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript Substring and Length inbuilt functions as:

```
<p><%= post.content.substring(0, 100) + "..." %></p>
```